# Solid sphere with a cylindrical hole through center (bead shaped solid)

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I am trying to draw a *solid* sphere with a cylindrical drilled through its center. The best I have been able to do is:

[image]

which does not show it is solid.  How do I make it more *solid* in appearance?

### Notes:

- The code is adapted from [Strange problems in 3D-Plots TikZ: Missing parts and axes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11975/strange-problems-in-3d-plots-tikz-missing-parts-and-axes/11981#11981)
- Besides a nice color version, I also need to be able to copy this in black and white so if you have suggestions on that, that would be helpful as well.
- Eventually need to be able to label the two radii: the sphere's and the cylinder's.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
  samples=25,domain=0:360,y domain=-60:60,
  xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2,zmin=-1.2,zmax=1.2,
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},zlabel={$z$},
  axis lines=none]
\addplot3[surf,opacity=0.5]
  ({cos(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(x)*cos(y)}, {1.5*sin(y)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the `colormap/blackwhite` paprameter for `axis` environment from PGF manual and `shader` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
  samples=25,domain=0:360,y domain=-60:60,
  xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2,zmin=-1.2,zmax=1.2,
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},zlabel={$z$},
  axis lines=none,
  colormap/blackwhite]
\addplot3[surf,opacity=0.5,shader=interp]
  ({cos(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(x)*cos(y)}, {1.5*sin(y)});
\end{axis}
\fill[top color=white,bottom color=blue!10,middle color=gray,shading=axis,opacity=0.25] (5.25,2) circle (1.75cm and 0.6cm);% Bottom hole
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

**Update:**
For adding bottom hole, insert some code using `circle`.

[image]

Comment: That certainly helps with the black and white print version issue, but still does not quite look solid -- still appears to be just a shell of a sphere.